# Python : ignorable arguments in a class.

Tags: python, class, arguments

I have a class with 3 arguments, however, on occasion I would like to be able to only pass two arguments to that class, so if there was nothing passed to the third argument it would go to a default value.

What I want to do is something like this (pseudo code)

```
class car(object):

    def __init__(self, color, length, numWheels):

          if numWheels == null:
              numWheels = 4
```

Is there a method to do this in Py?

Comment: Don't forget to Google things: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+argument+default+value immediately turns up https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *default parameter value*:

```
def __init__(self, color, length, numWheels = 4):
```

so you can call it like:

```
c = car('black', 5, 8)
c = car('black', 5)
```

**Notes:**

- I would recommend you to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Name your class `Car` instead of `car`.
- `null` doesn't exist in Python. You should read about `None` (which is similar).
- While using a default parameter value, you have to be aware that if it's a mutable object, it will be evaluated *once*, not each time an object is created.

Comment: would this not always set numWheels to 4? even iff an argument was passed in?

Comment: No, it's called default parameter value.

Comment: Just be aware that if the default value of an argument is a mutable object, it will be evaluated at compile time, not at run time. This might lead to unexpected behaviour if you are not Dutch.